# Should a table have a PK when it has a unique FK?

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have this case :

[image]

`UserSettings` is not really a junction table since it only has one FK, which is gonna be unique, one `UserSettings` for one User. Should `UserSettings` have `UserId` marked as Primary Key even if `UserId` is a unique FK or is it unnecessary ?

Comment: is setting just one column in the UserSettings Table or does more than one column describes a User's settings ? Plus if one user can have only one settings it makes perfect sense to make UserId a primary key in UserSettings Table

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you are putting the settings in a separate table?  This is an unusual design choice, if there is only one set of settings per user.

Comment: If UserId is intended to be unique then it should have a uniqueness constraint (UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY) on it. By convention one key per table is designated "primary" key but what really matters is that the key is being enforced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ensure this "which is gonna be unique" requirement then you'll need to define UserID either as UNIQUE or as Primary Key constraint.

Answer (score 2):

`UserSettings` should ideally not exist. Logically, all of this is one table.

If you wish to keep a separate table (which might be useful for performance or architecture) you should probably use the same primary key. In other words, `UserSettings` should use the FK as the PK. This is advantageous for performance, storage space and simplicity.

Comment: It would make perfect sense to have `UserSettings` as a separate table if not every `User` has a `UserSettings` record..

Comment: @thebjorn valid concern. Or just make all settings nullable columns. My experience is that this makes for easier application design.

Comment: @usr What about DB design then ?

Comment: @ThomasHaratyk what about it? Not sure what you mean.

Comment: If users and settings are things that have different sets of attributes then logically they belong in distinct tables. Bundling them together and permitting nulls everywhere is not a wise database design strategy and would be an unjustified compromise of data integrity - a heavy price to pay for making application design "easier".

Comment: @usr sqlvogel's answer is exactly what I meant by database design (you can also add my concern about the storage space of NULL values)

Comment: @ThomasHaratyk I totally respect your concern. I just have different practical experience with this issue. I rarely find it helpful to split off columns or groups of columns if there is a 1:1 relationship (or a 0:1 relationship). I think if you drove your approach to its logical conclusion you would end up with very many such tables in many typical schemas. This is not being done in my experience and I would not wish for it, except for under special circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

With few exceptions, every table should have a primary key.  So yes, I would make it a primary key even if it is also a foreign key.